# How can I create separate output lines, depending on the Thread the output is coming from?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sorting, io

I have a program that implements two different sort algorithms. I am testing both algorithms in parallel by launching them in separate threads. I would like to be able to view the results of the sort operation, *as they are taking place in each thread*, and am trying to keep these results on the same line (for each thread).

> Ex:
>       Arr1= 3 5 8 11 16 ... (Sort output from thread 1)
>       Arr2= 4 7 9 10 17 ... (Sort output from thread 2)

I have accomplishing this with `Thread.sleep(xxx)` after the main logic runs, but this works only when I have just one thread. If I put this delay in both threads it displays something like this:

> Arr1=
>   Arr2=Arr1 [i] Arr2[i] Arr1[i+1] Arr2[i+2] ...

In other words, output from both sorts is being displayed on the same line.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class sortareBubbleSort extends Thread {
    int nre, min, max;

    public sortareBubbleSort(int nre, int min, int max) {
        this.nre = nre;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public void run() {
        int[] x = new int[nre];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++)
            x[i] = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
        boolean doMore = true;
        while (doMore) {
            doMore = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
                if (x[i] > x[i + 1]) {
                    int temp = x[i];
                    x[i] = x[i + 1];
                    x[i + 1] = temp;
                    doMore = true;

                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nHere is the sorted array with BubbleSort:");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
        System.out.print("\n");

    }
}

class sortareHeapSort extends Thread {
    int nre, min, max;

    public sortareHeapSort(int nre, int min, int max) {
        this.nre = nre;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public void run() {
        int[] x = new int[nre];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++)
            x[i] = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));

        PriorityQueue<Integer> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
        for (int w : x)
            pQueue.add(w);
        for (int k = 0; k < x.length; k++)
            x[k] = pQueue.poll();

        // Print the array
        System.out.println("\nHere is the sorted array with HeapSort:");
        for (int w : x)
            System.out.print(w + "  ");
    }
}

public class TestThread {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sortareBubbleSort fir1;
        sortareHeapSort fir2;
        fir1 = new sortareBubbleSort(10, 1, 100);
        fir2 = new sortareHeapSort(10, 100, 200);
        fir1.start();
        fir2.start();
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Cool I think, he does mean something else.

Comment: Build the whole output as one String and use some logger (for instance Slf4J with Logback) to let it print.

Comment: You don't have that level of control over the typical console device, unfortunately. You would have to implement your own 'output' console that was aware of the thread sources, and could separate their respective output to dedicated 'lines'. I question the importance of doing this, related to the effort required to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make a synchronized static method just to print the array, so the first thread that finishes its job gets the lock and release it only when it prints the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you print in separate columns instead of lines:

```
Bubblesort    Heapsort
3             
              4
5             
8
              7
11             
              9
16
              10
              17
```

This would be much easier to achieve, just print each result on a new line and adjust the indentation depending on the sort algorithm.